# Specific Cast invaild exception for context to activity

Tags: xamarin.android

Closing app using following code

```
   Context CurrentContext = Android.App.Application.Context;

    public void CloseByFinish()
    {
        var activity = (Activity)CurrentContext;

        activity.FinishAffinity();

    }
```

getting specific cast invalid exception 
using xamarin 2.5

Comment: The easier way to close the app would just be Environment.Exit(0);  then you don't really need to mess around with casts etc. you can use either the System, or Java assembly for your Environment call.

Comment: Can you show some more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Specific Cast invalid exception for context to activity

You can't convert `Android.App.Application.Context` to `Activity`, as illustrated in the following diagram, they are the different type.

[image]

As [David Wasser said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39583184/calling-finishaffinity-does-not-destroy-android-app-or-activity-activitys-da) ;

> `FinishAffinity()` is not used to "close an application". It is used to remove a number of `Activity`s belonging to a specific application from the current task (which may contain `Activity`s belonging to multiple applications).
>
> Even if you finish all of the `Activity`s in your application, the OS process hosting your app does not automatically go away (as it does when you call `System.exit()`). Android will eventually kill your process when it gets around to it. You have no control over this (and that is intentional).

## Suggestion :

You could close your app by using the following code :

```
private void CloseApp()
{
    Java.Lang.JavaSystem.Exit(0);// Close this app process
    Android.OS.Process.KillProcess(Android.OS.Process.MyPid());
}
```

## Update  :

If  you use `FinishAffinity` in an `Activity`, modify your code like this :

```
public void CloseByFinish()
{
    this.FinishAffinity();
}
```

Comment: Before closing application  started background service .

Comment: Is this code   Java.Lang.JavaSystem.Exit(0);// Close this app process
    Android.OS.Process.KillProcess(Android.OS.Process.MyPid()); will close app background service ??

Comment: @SwapnilWakchaure, yes. So you just need to finish all `Activity` in your project and the `Service` still running?

Comment: @SwapnilWakchaure, I have update my answer, you may check it.

Comment: I had write CloseByFinish method in DependencyService how can we gor context or this in DependencyService

Comment: @SwapnilWakchaure, try using :  `var activity = Forms.Context as MainActivity`.

Comment: Forms.Context is obsolete in xamarin.forms 2.5

Comment: @SwapnilWakchaure, you still can use `Forms.Context ` to implement your feature. And you could use `Context` instead, but I didn't test it.